# React Js click event within a for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with React. This is my code:

```
var rows = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= this.state.numberOfPages; i++) {
    rows.push(<li key={i.toString()} onClick={() => this.getResults(i)}><a href="#">{i}</a></li>)
};
```

`getResults()` function is as simple as:

```
getResults: function(page = this.state.currentPage) {
    console.log(page);
},
```

`this.state.numberOfPages` is equal to 3. The issue is that, when I click on `<li>` tags, 4 is always showed in console. However `<li>` values are showed correctly in the HTML. I can't understand why is always being evaluated the last `i` value when it is passed by parameter.

**A detail:**

In React Console, key property are correct too. The problem is `with the parameter only`.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English.

Comment: Do you realize that your loop is probably already executed?

Comment: @AndyRay I tried it, unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the duplicated answer, you need to close over the variable with some inner function. Using `map` is an easy way to achieve this:

```
var rows = new Array(this.state.numberOfPages).fill(0).map( ( zero, index ) =>
    <li key={index} onClick={() => this.getResults(index)}>
        <a href="#">{index}</a>
    </li>
)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I found a shorter way! You can do this: onClick={this.getResults.bind(this, i) and it works