# Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. React two button function conflict

Tags: reactjs

In React, I have two buttons being rendered and I am getting this warning:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Content from './HomeItem';
import { Container, Row } from 'reactstrap';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const HomePage = props => {
  const tvshow = props.item;
  let res;

  if (tvshow.length > 0) {
    res = tvshow.map(res => (
      <Content item={res} onClick={props.onClick} onClick={props.onClick} />
    ));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row>{res}</Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Keys**

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity:

```
if (tvshow.length > 0) {
    res = tvshow.map((res,index) => (
      <Content item={res} key={index} onClick={props.onClick}/>
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Thanksss, I have another problem. No duplicate props allowed react/jsx-no-duplicate-props.

Comment: this is because onClick is being passed twice in your code. I've removed that duplicate onCLick in my snipped already. @Brandon

Comment: Okay, I see that. But how do I use props.onClick({data}) if I have two onClick functions?

Comment: Here is my HomeItem.js a:

const HomeItem = props => {
  function handleSubmit() {
    props.onClick({
      name: props.item.name,
      id: props.item.id
    });
  }

  function handleName() {
    props.onClick({
      name: props.item.name
    });
  }

Comment: Here is my App.js:
 handleSubmit(newFavorite) {}
 handleName(newFavorite) {}

render() {
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => (
              <HomePage
                item={this.state.SaveFavorite}
                onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                onClick={this.handleName}
              />
            )}
          />

Comment: In app.js you don't really have to name it as onClick. try this code
`<HomePage item={this.state.SaveFavorite} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} handleName={this.handleName} />`

Comment: and in HomeItem.js
`const HomeItem = props => { function handleSubmit() { props.handleSubmit({ name: props.item.name, id: props.item.id }); } function handleName() { props.handleName({ name: props.item.name }); }`

Comment: Hi thank you so much help but I got two error.
Uncaught TypeError: props.handleName is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: props.handleName is not a function
:(((

Comment: please share your code on jsfiddle or plunkr whichever suits you. 
probably you forgot to create handleName(){} in app.js or may be there are some spelling mistakes

Answer (score 1):

You should use key 
**Keys**

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity:

```
 onClick=(e,res)={
   console.log(res);
   }

  if (tvshow.length > 0) {
    res = tvshow.map((res,index) => (
      <Content item={res} key={index onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,res)} />
    ));
  }
```

Documentation:https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Thanksss, I have another problem.  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props

Comment: check this:https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-duplicate-props.md

Comment: I have two onClick functions, how do I use props.onClick({data})?

Comment: I tried your code, but both of my buttons still reading the same function and the error still there. :( 
Here is my HomeItem.js:

const HomeItem = props => {
  function handleSubmit() {
    props.onClick({
      name: props.item.name,
      id: props.item.id
    });
  }

  function handleName() {
    props.onClick({
      name: props.item.name
    });
  }

Comment: Here is my App.js:
 handleSubmit(newFavorite) {}
 handleName(newFavorite) {}

render() {
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => (
              <HomePage
                item={this.state.SaveFavorite}
                onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                onClick={this.handleName}
              />
            )}
          />

Comment: can you create stackblitz or ref this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338981/react-js-click-event-within-a-for-loop